# Visual Studio 2010 PFX Code Signing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-signing, pfx, signtool

Sorry if asked before.

Using Visual Studio 2010, I am trying to sign my assemblies with a pfx file so that on build it does the same work as:

```
signtool sign /f myKey.pfx /p password1 myDll.dll
```

I have `myKey.pfx` set as the strong name key file with 'Sign the assembly' checked in the Project Properties -> Signing tab.

Is this what the Signing tab does or am I trying to use it for something incorrectly.

I'm sure that I am missing something simple what is it?

Edit: just to clarify, I'm looking for alternatives to just adding a Post-Build script to shell the signing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using a VB Script in the PreBuild event of my Setup / Deployment Project which ran over all .DLL and .EXE files in the OBJ folders for my project and ran the signtool command (including full path to the SDK)

```
Sub ShowSubFolders(keyFile, fFolder)
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(fFolder.Path)
    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
    For Each objFile in colFiles
        If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "DLL" Or UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "EXE" Then
            'Wscript.Echo objFile
            Dim objResult
            Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    
            objResult = objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\signtool"" sign /f " & keyFile & " """ & objFile & """", 0, True)
        End If
    Next

    For Each Subfolder in fFolder.SubFolders
        Call ShowSubFolders(keyFile, Subfolder)
    Next
End Sub
```