# How to Code Sign EXE File in Visual Studio Instead of DLL

Tags: visual-studio, signtool

MY MAIN QUESTION IS: How do I get my project's EXE file signed after a successful build?

I am already successfully code signing my .NET project assembly's DLL file in Visual Studio 2022 through a post-build event that calls SignTool.exe. My post-build event calls SignTool.exe once for the $(TargetPath) via a simple CMD batch script that also outputs some debug information.

My one-line post-build event invokes my batch script like this:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release call "$(ProjectDir)\..\MYBATCHSCRIPT.BAT" $(TargetPath)
```

The file MYBATCHSCRIPT.BAT simply states:

```
@echo off
signtool.exe sign /f "c:\certpath\cert.pfx" /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /p PASSWORD "%1"
echo Completed code signature for %1
```

The problem seems to be that the target getting signed each time is a DLL and not the expected project EXE file. That is, I get a signed XXXPROJECTXXX.DLL file, but the XXXPROJECTXXX.EXE file doesn't seem signed.

I can tell because I see a Digital Signatures tab with the proper information when I go to Windows Explorer, right-click on the resulting DLL file, and choose Properties.

No such tab exists on the EXE file's Properties screen.

Also, the results of my post-build event prove that only the DLL is ever signed, per my debug log (the ECHO command at bottom of MYBATCHSCRIPT.BAT).

Here's what I see when I edit my project file. As you can see, my expected output type is an EXE file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <RootNamespace>XXXPROJECTXXX</RootNamespace>
    <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
    <EnableDefaultContentItems>false</EnableDefaultContentItems>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>False</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

At first I thought that my problem may be because the project properties had the "Reference assembly" checkbox checked (causing ProduceReferenceAssembly to be set to True), thereby causing a DLL to be produced. But setting that to false still creates the DLL, and the EXE remains unsigned.

SO TO BREAK DOWN MY QUESTION:

- Any clues on getting my EXE file signed?
- Or are SignTool.exe and Visual Studio already behaving as they should--meaning that only the DLL should ever get signed and not the EXE?
- Or is my simple CMD batch script calling SignTool.exe once for the $(TargetPath) too simplistic, and should I instead rely on a more comprehensive algorithm to force-sign all my DLLs and EXEs, like what was proposed by [Seph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288747/seph) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8200060/2505567

Comment: If you are shipping customers an EXE then that is what you should sign, otherwise security software will not be happy about running it.   Your batch looks fine, so you're passing it the wrong target somehow.

Comment: How does $(TargetPath) end up being the path to the DLL then, instead of the EXE, given that my project's <OutputType> is "Exe"? That's what I am running into then.

Comment: The .bat file is the problem, it can only sign the DLL.  The EXE you get is *not* the $(TargetPath), it is the apphost.  Does the same thing that dotnet.exe does.

Comment: Then how do I get the path to the apphost? Because that sounds like it might solve my problem. And what do you mean about dotnet.exe?

Comment: Hmm, i think Hans was referring to peculiarities about a .NET Core project ,but here it's .NET 6. Interestingly I see similarities in how a separate, remotely-related issue thread says .NET Core handles generated DLLs versus EXEs, but I still don't know what to make of all of this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286725/change-net-core-application-generated-exe-description

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying MYBATCHSCRIPT.BAT as follows in order to sign both DLL and EXE files:

```
@echo off
signtool.exe sign /f "c:\certpath\cert.pfx" /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /p PASSWORD "%1"
echo Completed code signature for %1

REM The above signs the DLL. Below, we sign the EXE.
set executable=%1%
set executable=%executable:.dll=.exe%
signtool.exe sign /f "c:\certpath\cert.pfx" /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /p PASSWORD "%executable%"
echo Completed code signature for %executable%
```